# Pandas lookup/pivot using column headings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a table containing watershed IDs and land cover classes:

```
WatershedID LandCover
          2      Corn
          8      Corn
          2       Soy
          8       Soy
```

and a separate lookup table which contains the area for each watershed/land cover combination:

```
WatershedID  Corn  Soy
          2    14    1
          3     2   14
          5    18    8
          7    21    2
          8     6   31
```

What I would like to do is to append a column to the first table which contains the corresponding row/column value in the lookup table, like so:

```
WatershedID LandCover   Area
          2      Corn     14
          8      Corn      6
          2       Soy      1
          8       Soy     31
```

I've managed to do this by iterating with a for loop:

```
areas = []
for watershed_id, land_cover in tableA.iterrows():
    areas.append(tableB.loc[watershed_id][land_cover]
```

but given the size of my tables, this is slow. Is there a faster way to do this that doesn't involve iteration?  I've been experimenting with MultiIndexing and pivot tables, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df3 = df2.set_index('WatershedID').unstack().reset_index()
df3.columns = ['LandCover','WatershedID','Area']
print (df3)
  LandCover  WatershedID  Area
0      Corn            2    14
1      Corn            3     2
2      Corn            5    18
3      Corn            7    21
4      Corn            8     6
5       Soy            2     1
6       Soy            3    14
7       Soy            5     8
8       Soy            7     2
9       Soy            8    31

print (pd.merge(df1,df3))
   WatershedID LandCover  Area
0            2      Corn    14
1            8      Corn     6
2            2       Soy     1
3            8       Soy    31
```

If there are more same columns you need specify columns for join:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df3, on=['WatershedID','LandCover']))
   WatershedID LandCover  Area
0            2      Corn    14
1            8      Corn     6
2            2       Soy     1
3            8       Soy    31
```